# "in roadmap" vs "on roadmap"

Tags: prepositions

In software development planning, a roadmap is used to describe what lies ahead. In our industry, we say: "put it in the roadmap". But when it comes to maps, I would search "on" a map.

Do I say something is "in the roadmap" or "on the roadmap"?

Comment: With the map folded up, it's *in* the roadmap.  Spread the map out on the table and it's *on* the roadmap.  (Seriously, if you consider the metaphor.)

Answer (score 1):

An English idiom is:  **put (someone, something, or some place) on the map**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/map)

> To make some place or thing very famous or renowned; to establish some
>   place as being remarkable or noteworthy.

It works nicely here in your question:

> In our industry, we have "put x on the map".